flutter run error eventhough all configurations and settings are correct
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\sagil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.5.11-hotspot\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\User
s\sagil.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3e88cec1990d24c89764a2425273571a\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\sagil.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3e88cec1990d24c89764a2425273571a\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

i tried with jdk version 17 and different versions of connectivity_plus...
tried to run after flutter clean and flutter pub get..

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Parameter format not correct -
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.


File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
Searched Location:
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ahmed1\student management\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ahmed1\student management\android\app\src\google-services.json

